# How to replace one element of array inside loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

There is an array `arr = [1, 2, "a", 4, 5];`. Using loop (for...of) every element of array must be pushed inside another empty array `result = [];`.

But, inside `arr` there is an element that needed to be replaced inside loop. Here, we need to replace string "a" with number 3 and than push it inside array `result`.

In the end we need to get an array `result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];`. As you can see string "a" was replaced and instead number 3 was pushed.

!Important initial array `arr` shouldn't be mutated and loop is a required condition.

Example:

```
const arr = [1, 2, "a", 4, 5];
const result = [];

for(let elem of arr) {
  if(typeof elem === "string") {
    // changing elem to number 3 and pushing it into result array instead of "a"
  }
// ...
}
```

Tried use several different array methods, but it didn't help.

Comment: why not result.push(3)? also you could use map, btw what does the 3 refer to, is it always 3 or the index of the array

Comment: use `for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)` if u want acces to index. or both `map` and `forEach` also gives access to index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the string "a" with the number 3 and push every element into a new array using the for...of loop as follows:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, "a", 4, 5];
const result = [];

for (let elem of arr) {
  if (typeof elem === "string" && elem === "a") {
    // replace "a" with number 3 and push it into the result array
    result.push(3);
  } else {
    // push the current element into the result array
    result.push(elem);
  }
}

console.log(result); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Also note that ‘typeof elem === "string"’ is redundant with the strict equality check on “a”

Answer (score 0):

Just use an [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

here 3 each time

```js
const arr = [1, 2, "a", 4, 5, "b"];
const result = arr.map(item => typeof item === "string" ? 3 : item)
console.log(result)
```

Here index+1

```js
const arr = [1, 2, "a", 4, 5, "b"];
const result = arr.map((item, i) => typeof item === "string" ? i + 1 : item)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Allowed to only use loop, like for...of, for(let...)

Comment: .map is also an iterator...

Comment: yes, but a requirement mentioned allowing using only loop iterators

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) here. Something like:

```js
const reducer = (acc, v, i) => 
  [...acc, isNaN(+v) ? (acc[i-1] || 0) + 1 : +v];

const arr = [1, 2, "a", 4, 5];
const result = arr.reduce(reducer, []);
console.log(`in: ${JSON.stringify(arr)}`);
console.log(`out: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);

const arr2 = ["b", 2, "a", 4, 5];
const result2 = arr2.reduce(reducer, []);
console.log(`in: ${JSON.stringify(arr2)}`);
console.log(`out: ${JSON.stringify(result2)}`);

const arr3 = ["b", 2, "a", 4, "5"];
const result3 = arr3.reduce(reducer, []);
console.log(`in: ${JSON.stringify(arr3)}`);
console.log(`out: ${JSON.stringify(result3)}`);

// or in increments by choice
const reducerFactory = step => (acc, v, i) => 
  [...acc, isNaN(+v) ? (acc[i-1] || 0) + step : +v];

const arr4 = ["b", 4, "a", 8, 10, "12"];
const result4 = arr4.reduce(reducerFactory(2), []);
console.log(`in: ${JSON.stringify(arr4)}`);
console.log(`out: ${JSON.stringify(result4)}`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```